# Retrieve Database Schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-schema

I want to know, how can I retrieve Sql-Database schema informations such as Tables, Columns and Their relation between Tables and etc. I know it's possible if I execute different particular queries on Master Database and the targeted Database. But Is there any efficient way to retrieve schema of database ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this project on codeplex:
http://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/releases/view/71696

Comment: Glad to see you vahid, thanks for your reply that was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the [database metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx) via `GetSchema` method of `Connection` class.

Answer (score 2):

try to follow those articles.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309681/en

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107/en

Regards

Comment: Holy macaroni ... you posted links in Italian! :)

Comment: Yes, but there is another language is there. Our common language. CODE. :D

Comment: Yeah, plus there's Google translate to make things easy.

Comment: Yeah,in fact, use the translator a lot, but unfortunately sometimes if you do not notice very strange things come out which could then be misinterpreted. Bye:)

Comment: Unbroken English links :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309681

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310107

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetSchema` method of the `SqlConnection` class:

`DataTable t = _conn.GetSchema("Tables")`;

For more info read the MSDN article [Retrieving Database Schema Information (ADO.NET).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

GetSchema and Schema Collections

The Connection classes in each of the .NET Framework managed providers implement a GetSchema method which is used to retrieve schema information about the database that is currently connected, and the schema information returned from the GetSchema method comes in the form of a DataTable. The GetSchema method is an overloaded method that provides optional parameters for specifying the schema collection to return, and restricting the amount of information returned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934(v=vs.110).aspx